# How many possibilities on a binary?

Tags: php, binary

In an integer encoding of 8 bits `10101010` you have 0-255 possibilities.

In total 256 different possibilities as there are 8 1s and 0s. How many different possibilities would I get if I had 10 bits instead of 8?

How would I calculate that in PHP?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I assume you are thinking of binary rather than hexadecimal? Binary is base 2 (hence either 0 or 1s) where as Hexadecimal is base 16.

Assuming you are talking about binary:

- If you have 8 bits you have 2<sup>8</sup> possibilities.
- If you have 9 bits you have 2<sup>9</sup> possibilities.
- If you have 10 bits you have 2<sup>10</sup> possibilities.

Etc...

You can therefore use the PHP [pow](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php) function:

```
$possibilities = pow(2, 10);
```

Comment: are you absolutely sure what i mean ? that gives me a 1024 posibilities

Comment: @Val assuming you are talking about binary, then yes. If you had 10 bits (where each bit is 0 or 1) you could store the numbers between 0 - 1023. (So there are 1024 total different possibilities)

Comment: Yes that is right, to put it another way, each time you add a binary bit, you double the the number of possibilities, just as when you add a decimal digit, you multiply the number of possibilities by 10.

Answer (score 2):

As much as I *love* the idea to send a query to SQL Server for this, the OP could appreciate a pure PHP implementation.

I suggest this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
function howmanypossibilities($digits) {
    preg_match_all('{<b>.+= (.+?)</b>}',·
    file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/search?q=2**'.$digits), $matches);
    return str_replace('<font size=-2> </font>', ',', "{$matches[1][0]}\n");
}

print howmanypossibilities(10);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be 2^10  (2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2)

In SQL Server

```
SELECT 2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2

SELECT POWER(2,10)
```

Answer (score 0):

With 8 bits, you have a *range* of [0 - 255] for unsigned numbers (256 possible values including 0).

For the general case, you have `2^x` number of possible values, where `x` is the number of bits. Therefore, with 10 bits you have `2^10 = 1024` possible values.

To calculate this in PHP, simply use the `pow` function:

```
pow ( number $base , number $exp )
```

e.g.

`echo pow(2, 10)` will output 1024.